# Convert theme from ASP.net-based site to Drupal

Tags: theming

I'm supposed have to launch a Drupal 6 site within 4-6 weeks. Most of the content is already loaded into Drupal. But I'm having a dilemna about the fastest way to approach theming. Our university web developer is using Sitefinity (ASP.net) while I chose Drupal for our site. He gave me a copy of the unfinished template files a month ago (HTML, CSS, JS, images) which were designed using Blueprint CSS. I have just received  access to the main university site including admin priviledges. Since it is apparent that a lot of the final design was created using a skinning feature in Sitefinity, I downloaded the complete site using WinHTTrack and am trying to cobble together my "interpretation" of the design using the main CSS file done with Blueprint, and the Sitefinity system CSS files. The Sitefinity CSS files have their own layout which is based on percentages. I'm looking at creating either a Zen or Fusion based theme. I've tried removing all the Sitefinity styling and re-building the design from scratch using Blueprint in Dreamweaver.But I'm afraid this is a waste of time. I'd appreciate some advice on how others would approach replicating an ASP.net template for use in Drupal. While not at all familiar with Sitefinity, I did download a copy of all the files from the server in case they could be used to convert the layout to Drupal, although I know PHP and ASP.net themes are nothing like each other. Any strategies would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need create a new theme.

you can't just export from one to another.

The best place to start is learn how create a drupal theme, and the best place for learn that is in  the handbook:

http://drupal.org/documentation/theme

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any tool doing something automatic for you. Just take the ASP.net as as a prototype and start again with a solid base theme like zen.

Answer (score 0):

Gnuget and Betaride are both right. Additionally though, if the designer worked with the Blueprint framework, it might be best to build your custom theme on the [Blueprint](http://drupal.org/project/blueprint) theme.

Answer (score 0):

When converting from a former CMS theme to a Drupal theme, really the only thing that will be of much use is the CSS and JS files - even those will have to be heavily edited in order to work with Drupal.

I would suggest choosing a solid base theme and then use the previous CMS's CSS and JS as a starting point for building your own styles for the new Drupal theme. You will have to completely re-write most of the CSS selectors (and any JS that uses CSS-type selectors), since the HTML structure of the previous CMS will probably not match-up with the HTML that Drupal gives you.

If you do choose to build a Fusion-based Drupal theme, you can also get great support for building your theme at http://fusiondrupalthemes.com/forum/using-fusion